# output not created using lgreek.sty

Tags: fonts, greek

My code are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lgreek}

\begin{document}

\begin{greek}
To~u d`e poso~u t`o m'en >esti diwrism'enon, t`o d`e suneqes.
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

I am using `LaTeX/PDFLaTeX` in `MikTeX v2.9` to generate the output, and I am not sure how to clear the font error, the `.log` file shown below:

```
Sorry, but maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Epub/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

! Font LG/cmr/m/n/10=grreg10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.6 \begin{greek}
```

Please suggest...

Comment: Can you use `XeLaTeX`? I'm using Papeeria and your code with `XeLaTeX` works correctly.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm in the situation to use either LaTeX or PDFLaTeX in MikTeX v2.9 (Windows OS) only...

Comment: Also with PDFLaTeX your code works well. Try updating your MikTeX with the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid `lgreek`, because the fonts it defines are only available as bitmaps.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}

\newenvironment{greek}
  {\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}}
  {\end{otherlanguage*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{greek}
To~u d`e poso~u t`o m'en >esti diwrism'enon, t`o d`e suneqes.
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here's the output with `lgreek`:

[image]